# Align two sets of x-y coordinates that nominally cover the same "region"

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to compare multiple data sets, where each data set has the following format: (x-coordinate, y-coordinate, value). Now each of the data sets nominally cover the same region in x-y space, but the x-y sampling in each data set is not identical.

What is a good way to "align" the two sets of coordinates so that the associated values can be compared? I can work with either:

- "move" one set of coordinates to overlap with the other set of coordinates
- interpolate one of values so that a fresh set of approx values is generated corresponding to the other coordinate system.

I tried using ["Interpolation on Scattered Data"](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Interpolation-on-Scattered-Data.html), but the result from this contained way too many NaN values.

Of note, the x-y region covered is not necessarily rectangular, it can be an arbitrary shape (e.g. say, shaped like a wrench).

Comment: You should provide a simple data set for demonstration. Also it is not clear to me if the absolute x-y coordinate is important for your comparison. Do you want to compare the values corresponding to the absolute coordinate or is it more a relative coordinate? Please provide data and at least some code to discuss about.

Comment: I would use the mentioned `griddata`. Where do you have NaNs? at the border where you would have to extrapolate?

Comment: @Andy the NaNs show up in the middle of the grid actually, not at the edges. Edged would have made sense. :-/

Comment: @GeorgW. The absolute coordinate numbers are not important; their only purpose is to align the values that are to be compared. I apologize, I don't own the data and so cannot post examples online. :-)

Comment: "I don't own the data and so cannot post examples online" is not a good excuse. Obviously someone needs your input data to debug the NaNs in the output. If you can't post your original data you have to create a small sample set which shows the error manually. This is the same as George  W. asked for in the FIRST comment

Comment: @Andy Sure, I understand. Other than debugging, though, you're saying that griddata should be the best way to achieve this? If I know that, then I can at least pause looking for alternative solutions, and work on debugging the griddata solution. :-)